# How to create VSTS work item tags via vsts-node-api module?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to create work item tags using vsts-node-api module, it seems there is no function in WorkItemTrackingApi for this at the moment. Is there any alternative for this?

Following is the location of Work item API wrapper 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api/blob/master/api/WorkItemTrackingApi.ts

Comment: Do you try it with updateWorkItem function?

Comment: @Starain, Yes Starin I tried, both createWorkItem and updateWorkItem doesn't have an option to create Tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is created automatically when you use "createWorkItem" and "updateWorkItem" method.

Referring to the code I provided in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631747/how-to-create-work-items-using-visual-studio-team-services-client-for-node-js-v), update the code to following:

```
let wijson = [{ "op": "add", "path": "/fields/System.Title", "value": "Task created from Node JS" }, { "op": "add", "path": "/fields/System.Tags", "value": "Tag1; Tag2" }];
```