# Work item creation issue in TFS 2015.2 (with vsts-node-api)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm getting following error when creating bug item in TFS 2015.2 (on premise) via vso-node-api package, however same code is working perfectly in my VSTS (online) subscription.

> Error: Failed Request: Bad Request(400) - TF401349: An unexpected error has occurred, please verify your request and try again.
> Status Code: 400

I'm using the WorkItemTrackingApi/createWorkItem function in vso-node-api library to create the work item. Following is the sample code I have used to create work items.

**WorkItemCreator.ts**

```
import * as vm from 'vso-node-api/WebApi';
import * as wa from 'vso-node-api/WorkItemTrackingApi';
import * as wi from 'vso-node-api/interfaces/WorkItemTrackingInterfaces';
import * as vss from 'vso-node-api/interfaces/Common/VSSInterfaces';
import * as core from 'vso-node-api/interfaces/CoreInterfaces';
import tl = require('vsts-task-lib/task');

export class WorkItemCreator {
    workItemType: string = "Bug";
    fieldsToRetrieve: string[] = ["System.State", "System.Title"];

    collectionUrl: string;
    projName: string;
    accessToken: string;
    vstsWI: wa.IWorkItemTrackingApi;
    projectId: string;

    constructor() {
        console.log("Initializing Workitem Creator...");
        console.log("Retrieving enviornment values...");
        this.collectionUrl = process.env["SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI"];
        this.projName = process.env["SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT"];
        this.projectId = process.env["SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID"];

        console.log("SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI: " + this.collectionUrl);
        console.log("SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT: " + this.projName);

        this.accessToken = this.getAccessToken();
        let creds = vm.getBearerHandler(this.accessToken);
        let connection = new vm.WebApi(this.collectionUrl, creds);
        this.vstsWI = connection.getWorkItemTrackingApi();
    }

    /**
     * Create Work Items
     */
    public createWorkItems(workItems: Array<BugItem>) {
        workItems.forEach(workItem => {
            let selectWorkItemsQry = { query: "Select [System.Id] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = '" + this.workItemType + "' AND [System.Title] = '" + workItem.title + "'" };
            this.getWorkitem(this.projName, this.projectId, selectWorkItemsQry).then((qr: wi.WorkItemQueryResult) => {
                console.log("WorkItem Count:" + qr.workItems.length);
                if (qr.workItems.length == 0) {
                    console.log("Creating WorkItem '" + workItem.title + "' in project '" + this.projName + "'");
                    let xs: string[] = ["TagX", "TagY", "TagZ"];
                    console.log("Tags: " + xs);
                    this.createWorkitem(this.projName, this.workItemType, workItem.title, workItem.description, workItem.severity, xs);
                }
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                    console.error("Failed to retrieve WorkItem by title '" + workItem.title + "' Error: " + e);
            });
        });        
    }

    //Get acces token
    private getAccessToken(): string {
        tl.debug("Getting credentials for local feeds");
        let auth = tl.getEndpointAuthorization("SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION", false);
        if (auth.scheme === "OAuth") {
            console.log("Token retrieved: " + auth.parameters["AccessToken"]);
            tl.debug("Token retrieved: " + auth.parameters["AccessToken"]);
            return auth.parameters["AccessToken"];
        }
        else {
            tl.warning("Could not retrieve authentication token for Workitem creation.");
        }
    }


    //Create Workitem
    private createWorkitem(projectName: string, witype: string, title: string, description: string, severity: string, tagsCollection: string[]) {
        let wijson: vss.JsonPatchDocument = [
            { "op": "add", "path": "/fields/System.Title", "value": title },
        ];

        this.vstsWI.createWorkItem(null, wijson, projectName, witype, null, null).then((workitem: wi.WorkItem) => {
            console.log("WorkItem '" + workitem.id + "' Created");
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.error("Failed to create work item for '" + title + "' Error: " + e);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get Workitems
     */
    private getWorkitem(projectName: string, teamProjectId: string, wiqlQuery: wi.Wiql): Promise<wi.WorkItemQueryResult> {
        console.log(wiqlQuery.query);
        let teamContext: core.TeamContext = { project: projectName, projectId: teamProjectId, team: "", teamId: "" };
        return this.vstsWI.queryByWiql(wiqlQuery, teamContext, null, null);
    }
}

/**
 * BugItem
 */
export class BugItem {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    severity: string;

    constructor(title: string, description: string, severity: string) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.severity = severity;
    }
}
```

**App.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../definitions/node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../definitions/minimatch.d.ts" />
const Critical = "1 - Critical";
const Low = "4 - Low";

import * as wIc from './WorkItemCreator';

var x = new wIc.WorkItemCreator();
var fullCollection = new Array<wIc.BugItem>();

var itm1 = new wIc.BugItem("Bug1TitleItem1", "DescriptionCritical", Critical);
fullCollection.push(itm1);
var itm6 = new wIc.BugItem("Bug1TitleItem6","DescriptionLow",Low);
fullCollection.push(itm6);

x.createWorkItems(fullCollection);
console.log("End.");
```

**Scopes:**
"scopes": [
"vso.build_execute",
"vso.work_write"
],

Comment: How did you authenticated to TFS server?

Comment: @Patrick: I have updated the question with the authentication logic.

Comment: Can you create the work item with the information in your code manually from web portal?

Comment: Yes Eddie, I was able to create work items manually.

Comment: Can you share the entire code so that I can try to reproduce it at my side?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT: I have added the full code as requested.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT: Updated the entire code.

Comment: Please note: I have observed getWorkitem() function is not getting failed when retrieving work items, it uses the same authentication as the createWorkitem() method. so it seems this is not an authentication related issue?

Comment: I will try it at my side, and yes, 400 bad request is not an auth issue, it is usually caused by the content you sent.

Comment: Thanks @Eddie-MSFT. Did you manage to recreate the issue?

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce this issue on TFS server, but haven't figure out the root cause yet.

Comment: Hi @Eddie-MSFT, I still could not resolve this issue, anything on your side?

Comment: Hi @BandR, Not yet. I will get you updated as soon as I get any information for this. And for now, I would recommend you use node-rest-client(https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client) to call the VSTS rest api url as an alternative way.

Comment: Not sure the root cause but this is caused by the authentication with access token. The code can works if change to use basic auth with username and password specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS 2015.3 doesn't support token based authentication. Alternative is to use Basic Authentication option. If the extension should be compatible with both VSTS and TFS, then you have to create a mechanism to use separate authentication mechanism for each deployment scenario. TFS 2017 support token authentication so that it will work fine with the PAT just like VSTS.

Answer (score 1):

As this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dfc9da69-dc6c-4307-98bb-35b08beee512/onprem-tfs-2015-rest-api-with-oauth?forum=tfsgeneral) points out, TFS on permise only supports NTLM and Kerberos for authentication. I would assume until MS update TFS, access token is never an option.

Comment: Your are correct that PAT support didn't come till TFS2017 on-prem.  But, per the code above, a PAT is not used.  They are using a bearer token.  For example the token created per build (and used by build tasks) is a JWT bearer token.

Comment: ... see the getAccessToken function.  It's getting the vss connection token created per build.  That's a JWT bearer token, not a PAT.

Comment: @bryanmac Yes PAT is not supported. That post said the only supported authentications were NTLM and Kerberos. I believe that means you can only use NTLM or Kerberos, right?

Comment: A JWT bearer token is not a PAT token.  You seem to be suggesting because PAT is not supported, it's left to NTLM/Kerberos.  When we built the build server we had the server generate a per build JWT bearer token which is sent down as part of the build job message.  That's what the agent uses for all communications back the TFS/VSTS server.