# Create User story with child tasks using ADO NodeJS sdk

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to create a bunch of user stories with children tasks like

```
1. UserStory1
  1.1 Task1,
  1.2 Task2
2. UserStory2
  2.1 Task1
  2.2 Task2
```

I know how to create tasks and user stories separately, I don't know how to link with children/parent using Node ADO SDK.
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already created the UserStory and Task, then you just need to call the `updateWorkItem()` method to link the user story and child tasks with the following json patch doc (update Task in this sample). See [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP#add-a-link) for details.

```
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
         "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
          "url": "UserStoryUrl",
          "attributes": {
                "isLocked": false,
                "comment": "Link to parent user story",
                "name": "Parent"
      }
    }
  }
```

You can also link the parent User Story when creating tasks, just get the User Story URL and integrate it to the json patch doc. Something like below:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "value": "Test"
  },

  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
         "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
          "url": "User Strory URL here",
          "attributes": {
                "isLocked": false,
                "comment": "Link to User Story as the parent work item",
                "name": "Parent"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Reference this thread : [How to create work items using Visual Studio Team Services Client for Node.js (vso-node-api)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631747/how-to-create-work-items-using-visual-studio-team-services-client-for-node-js-v)

```
async function createUS() {
    let wijson: vss.JsonPatchDocument = [{ "op": "add", "path": "/fields/System.Title", "value": "Task created from Node JS" }];
    let project: string = "Project";
    let witype: string = "User Story";
    let usWI: wi.WorkItem = await vstsWI.createWorkItem(null, wijson, project, witype);
    console.log(usWI.id);
}

createUS();

async function createTask() {
    let wijson: vss.JsonPatchDocument = [{ "op": "add", "path": "/fields/System.Title", "value": "Task created from Node JS" },{"op":"add","path":"/relations/-","value":{"rel":"System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse","url":"usWI.url","attributes":{"isLocked":false,"comment":"Link to parent User Story","name":"Parent"}}}];
    let project: string = "Project";
    let witype: string = "Task";
    let taskWI: wi.WorkItem = await vstsWI.createWorkItem(null, wijson, project, witype);
    console.log(taskWI.id);
}

createTask();
```